# Getting MasterUserPassword for AWS::RDS::DBCluster via SecretsManager in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, amazon-aurora, aws-secrets-manager

When creating an [`AWS::RDS::DBCluster`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-dbcluster.html)(Aurora-Serverless) in AWS CloudFormation, there is a property `MasterUserPassword` and its input is specified as [string](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-dbcluster.html#cfn-rds-dbcluster-masteruserpassword).

So, how to put a stack definition yaml so that RDS definition does not use a string but a random password generated by [`AWS::SecretsManager::Secret`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-secretsmanager-secret.html#cfn-secretsmanager-secret-secretstring)? Is it possible to reference Secrets-manager-generated password with `!Ref`, `!GetAtt` or any other means?

```
Resources:
  AuroraMysqlAppCredentialSecretStore:
    Type: AWS::SecretsManager::Secret
    Properties:
      Name: AuroraMysqlAppCredentialSecretStore
      GenerateSecretString:
        SecretStringTemplate: '{"username": "admin"}'
        GenerateStringKey: "password"
        PasswordLength: 30
        ExcludeCharacters: '"@/\'
  ApprovalDbCluster:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBCluster
    Properties:
      Engine: aurora
      EngineMode: serverless
      EngineVersion: '5.6'
      DatabaseName: MyDatabaseName
      MasterUsername: admin
      MasterUserPassword: # HOW TO REFERENCE THE PASSWORD HERE??
      DBClusterIdentifier: my-cluster-1
      BackupRetentionPeriod: 35
      DeletionProtection: false
      ScalingConfiguration:
        AutoPause: true
        MaxCapacity: 8
        MinCapacity: 2
        SecondsUntilAutoPause: 300
      DBSubnetGroupName: my-subnet-name
```

A final note: [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-dbcluster.html#cfn-rds-dbcluster-masteruserpassword) state that `MasterUserPassword` should not be specified if `SourceDBInstanceIdentifier` or `DBSnapshotIdentifier` property is given, but my configuration has neither, so apparently I should specify `MasterUserPassword`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic references in cloudformation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html

```
ApprovalDbCluster:
Type: AWS::RDS::DBCluster
Properties:
  Engine: aurora
  EngineMode: serverless
  EngineVersion: '5.6'
  DatabaseName: MyDatabaseName
  MasterUsername: admin
  MasterUserPassword: '{{resolve:ssm-secure:MasterPassword:10}}' #See link
```

Comment: The user and the password are supposed to be used by a Lambda function, so I doubt IAM is a fine option to interact with.